# c++ inner abstract class override. I'm trying to inherit from an abstract class that has an inner abstract class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to inherit from an abstract class that has an inner abstract class.
I want to get the following as a result of inheritance:
an inherited class with overloaded methods that has an inner class with overloaded methods and additional constructors.
Classes are templated

```
class A {
  void SomeMetod_A() = 0;
  class B {
    void SomeMetod_B() = 0;
  }
}

class C : public A {

How can I overload class B methods and add constructors here?

}
```

I tried to create an inner class in class C and inherit it from B, but this is not an overload of B

Comment: show what you tried. We can only help with code that you show

Comment: Only `virtual` methods can be pure (`= 0`). You seem to have missed quite a few things.

Comment: "Classes are tempalted" ?!? So much in this question suggests that the code you posted has little to do with the code that has the error. Please read about [mcve] and provide one

Comment: C++ is not Java.  There's no "ownership" relationship between a class defined in the scope of another (there may be some other access stuff you get though).  If you want to inherit from B, then inherit from it.  In the "fun, but you probably don't want to do it" you can inherit from *both* A and B from class C at the same time.  Multiple inheritance!

Comment: Is [this](https://godbolt.org/z/5x3Mx3oed) what you mean?

Comment: @TedLyngmo not really, sorry for the ambiguous question, I'll try to redo the question with part of my code. I would not want to inherit class B. I want to be able to override methods of class B in the heir. I would like the redefinition of B to be mandatory when inheriting from C : A. Otherwise, this may lead to an error

Answer (score 1):

You can directly here inherit from the inner class:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void SomeMetod_A() = 0;
  class B {
  public:
    virtual void SomeMetod_B() = 0;
  };
};

class C : public A {
public:
  void SomeMetod_A() override {}

  class BofC : public A::B {
  public:
    void SomeMetod_B() override {};
  };
};
```

Comment: Probably correct, but OP asks for overloaded methods, not overridden (edit: except in the title I just noticed).

Comment: @TedLyngmo `= 0` suggested me that user expects override instead of overload, but I agree that it's ambigous.